# Infinitely Scrolling or some other technique?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I’m working on a horizontal layout for UICollectionView to represent a timeline. Ideally, I’d like it to scroll infinitely, but I’m not sure what the right approach is.

For now I've started with a subclass of UICollectionViewLayout and a simple case of just 3 cells. I override the the scrollView delegate method `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and jump back to the center card and offset my model to match.

This works, except when the user scrolls quickly, and they reach the end of the other card. They get "caught" and have to release the collection view. When the view stops decelerating, the centering happens and they're able to continue.

I've got a demo [on GitHub](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBTimelineViewController).

I'm wondering if there's another approach, or something that I'm missing. I'm familiar with Apple's WWDC presentations on infinite scroll views, and have seen the demo project with the scrolling text, but I'm not sure how to make it work with paging or a collection view.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scrollViewDidScroll` if you want to know when the user has moved to a new page. As you discovered, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is not called if the user scrolls quickly, because the scroll view never stops moving.

I've adapted your code to:

1. Trigger on `scrollViewDidScroll` instead of `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.
2. Use the centre point of the collection view's bounds to test for index path (this then causes the cells to be updated when either the first or third cells are half way across the screen).
3. Set content offset directly instead of scrolling to index path, jumping a full page from the scroll view's current position.

Here's the code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self centerIfNecessary];
}

- (void)centerIfNecessary
{
    // Fetch the index path in the middle of the collection view
    NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x +
                                                                                             self.collectionView.bounds.size.width/2,
                                                                                             self.collectionView.contentOffset.y)];

    NSInteger row = visibleIndexPath.row;

    //  Three cases:    Row is 0, so we've moved left.
    //                  Row is 1, we haven't moved.
    //                  Row is 2, we've moved right.

    if (row == 0)
    {
        self.date = [[self calendar] dateBySubtractingDays:1 fromDate:self.date];
        self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x +
                                                        self.collectionView.bounds.size.width,
                                                        self.collectionView.contentOffset.y);
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
    else if (row == 2)
    {
        self.date = [[self calendar] dateByAddingDays:1 toDate:self.date];
        self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x -
                                                        self.collectionView.bounds.size.width,
                                                        self.collectionView.contentOffset.y);
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: How resilient is this code? It seems to work out of the box, but what if I change the size of my cells so more than one appear on screen?

Comment: The code above has two assumptions: That page size equals that of the collection view bounds, and that scrolling is horizontal. To generalise it you would need to use the `contentOffset` to establish the page offset, horizontally and/or vertically. The same principles apply in terms of using `scrollViewDidScroll` to inspect and adjust the `contentOffset`.

Answer (score -1):

You can make it look like an infinite scrolling scrollview by adding extra cells on both side of your horizontal UICollectionView. If the contentOffset get nearby left side, it shows exact same cells at right side of scroll content view. I think you can get idea from HFSwipeView - control in gitHub - how to achieve that problem.